# Event Handling of a background program

Tags: events, background, event-handling

Is there a way to let my program handle events like mouse movements and key strokes although the program is working in the background?!

Example : the user is working on notepad and I want my program to handle the events happening over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install mouse and keyboard hooks.